# No such module 'GoogleMobileAds'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode14

I am new to iOS app development and i was learning how to implement admob ads. After importing the google mobile ads sdk and initializing the sdk and showing test ads, I noticed something strange when I exited xcode and reopening. There is now a duplicated of the project . When I show the location of the folder, I saw `LearningAds.xcodeproj`  and `LearningAds.xcworkspace` The `LearningAds.xcworkspace` opens and even build on the simulator but the `LearningAds.xcodeproj`  does not even build it gives two  error saying

`No such module 'GoogleMobileAds'`